# Angular: Max Selections in Select Dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, select, quill

I am making a project in Angular(v5) and I want to make a select statement that drops down and shows a maximum of 7 elements with a scroll bar on the side that allows users to scroll to see the rest. I want to do this because currently on smaller screens, the contents of my select statement extend past the screen:

[image]

What is the best way to do this? I know I could import things like Semantic UI to do the exact thing I want:

[image]

But that is a lot of extra code for only one small feature. What is the best way to implment this with vanilla css/scss and html or angular?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to just use plain CSS to accomplish this. Just take your dropdown class (i.e `.dropdown-menu`) and add the properties to hide the overflow and set the height.

```
.dropdown-menu {
       max-height: 400px; /* Height you want menu to display */
       overflow-y: auto; /* Sets the container to scroll vertically */
}
```

Comment: A problem with this is when I set the height of my dropdown it makes my  top section of the editor become that size but I want it to keep its current height